# Custom Theme Additonal CSS "<" and ">" are transformed to "&gt" and "&lt"

Tags: themes, css, child-theme

Im using Elementor Child Theme and in there im sometimes writing "Additional CSS" and till yesterday everyting was working correct. But since today "<" and ">" are getting transformed to "&gt" and "&lt" in my css when loading the frontend of my website and thats why the css is no longer working...

Any clue where this comes from? I already deactivated every plugin and checked it again but it was still there. And also i checked it on other wordpress instances and it was not happening there.

Im running WordPress Version 6.1.1

Comment: Where are you adding the additional CSS?

Comment: @JacobPeattie under Appearance -> Themes -> Customize (my active theme) ->Additional CSS